# How to determine $\lim\limits_{x\to \pi/2 }\frac{\tan 2x}{x - \pi/2 }$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to \pi/2 } \frac{\tan 2x}{x-\pi/2}$$

Could anyone help me with this trigonometric limit? I'm trying to evaluate it without L'Hôpital's rule and derivation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting $x-\frac\pi2=y,$ as $x\to\frac\pi2,y\to0$

$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2}\frac{\tan2x}{x-\frac\pi2}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\tan 2(y+\frac\pi2)}y=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\tan 2y}y\text{ as }\tan(\pi+2y)=\tan2y$$

$$=2\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin 2y}{2y}\frac1{\lim_{y\to0}\cos2y}=2$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I have proof in College today and you helped me to study with this response.

Comment: @user73276, did you get the idea clear?

Answer (score 3):

By the definition of the derivative of the function $x\to \tan (2x)$ at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have:

$$\lim_{x \to \pi/2 } \frac{\tan 2x}{x-\pi/2}=\lim_{x \to \pi/2 } \frac{\tan 2x-\tan2\pi/2 }{x-\pi/2}=\left[2(1+\tan^2(2x))\right]_{x=\pi/2 }=2$$

Comment: Very Thanks!!!!

Comment: You're welcome.